# Proving $\vert \beta \mathbb{N} \vert \ge \vert X \vert$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, set-theory, compactness

Do you guys agree with my proof? I believe we can use to the density argument in $\mathbb{N}$ for the following problem. But I wanted to make sure I probably did so. Thanks!

$\def\N{{\mathbb N}}$
Prove if $X$ is a compact and separable space, then the cardinality of $\beta \N$ is at least as great as the cardinality of $X$.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Since $X$ is a compact and separable space, then by definition of separable, $\beta \N$ contains a countable dense subset in $X$, that is, there exists sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty = \beta \N$ of elements of the space such that every non-empty open subset of the space contains at least one element of the sequence. Therefore, $x_1\in X_1, x_2,x_3 \in X_2,\dots, x_i\in X_n$ where $X_1,X_2, \dots ,X_n$ are open subsets, non-empty, of $X$. Thus, the cardinality of $\beta \N$ is at least as great as the cardinality of $X$.

Comment: Your proof makes no sense to me. A major red flag is that the word "ultrafilter" does not appear even once in your proof. Do you know what $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m afraid that what you’ve written doesn’t make much sense. For instance, $\beta\Bbb N$ is uncountable, so it’s impossible that it is equal to the countable set $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. For that matter, there is no reason to think that $\beta\Bbb N$ contains **any** of the points of $X$: $X$ and $\beta\Bbb N$ can be disjoint from each other and so have **no** points in common. And your final sentence is a *non sequitur*: it does not in any way follow from what precedes it. I’ll give you a push in the right direction.

Let $D=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countable dense subset of $X$, and let $f:\Bbb N\to X:n\mapsto x_n$; $f$ is a continuous function from $\Bbb N$ with the discrete topology to the compact space $X$, so it has a continuous extension $f^\beta:\beta\Bbb N\to X$. Show that $f^\beta$ is a surjection, and you’ll have shown that $|\beta\Bbb N|\ge|X|$, as required. (Why?)

Comment: Thanks! So showing $f^\beta$ is onto allows us to construct a finite amount of elements that maps $\beta \mathbb{N}$ to $X$, thus onto and we can continue doing so, regardless of how many elements are within $\vert X\vert$

Comment: @brucemcmc: No, not at all. If $A$ and $B$ are any sets, and there is a surjection $f:A\to B$, then necessarily $|A|\ge |B|$; if $|A|$ were smaller than $|B|$, there could not possibly be a function mapping $A$ **onto** $B$.

Comment: Right, yes. I see what you're saying, clearly. I messed up what I was trying to say. Sorry.